# JQuery plugin help

Tags: jquery

I am building a little plugin for jquery and on the default options I want to give if it should be used "bind" or "live" for the click event. So I have

```
var defaults = { method: 'bind' /* or live */ };
var options = $.extend(defaults, options);
```

and the plugin continues

```
$(selector).**method**('click', function(event) { /* code  */});
```

Now, how can I make that the method is chosen by the default method value, without having to write the following.

```
if(options.method == 'live') { $(selector).live('click', function(event) { /* code  */}); } else { $(selector).bind('click', function(event) { /* code  */});}
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should do this:

```
$(selector)[options.method]('click', function(event) { 
  /* code  */
});
```

Cheers

Comment: Hahaha that's why you MUST love jQuery :)